# checking to see if a datagrid's metadata has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, metadata

I am currently setting the visibility property on a data grid column by using this work around:

*this is in the xaml.cs*

```
DataGrid.DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (null, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
```

However I need to check to make sure it has not already changed otherwise it will throw an exception. An example of what I have tried is below.

```
if (DataGrid.DataContextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DataGrid)) == 
    DataGrid.DataContextProperty.DefaultMetadata) // didn't work
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you doing there? If you need to override dependency property metadata, you should create a derived DataGrid and call OverrideMetadata in the static constructor of the derived class.

Comment: I am not sure, a lot of internet articles about how to use the visibility property on a data grid column since it does not exist in the framework and that is the solution that I came to, it works it just does not like being called if it has already been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that overriding property metadata for an existing type (a class that is not declared by your code, but is part of the WPF framework) is illegal.

Calling `DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid), ...)` only works by chance, as the class DataGrid does not already override metadata for the `FrameworkElement.DataContext` property. But you can't make any assumption about that, and MS may decide to change this in a future version of WPF.

You have to create a derived class and override metadata in the static class constructor, as shown in the MSDN documentation of [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx):

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    static MyDataGrid()
    {
        DataGrid.DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
    }
}
```